# nginx and passenger to run my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I'm new to Rails and trying to deploy my rails app (which runs perfectly on my computer using `rails server`) on to a server.

My server has `nginx` and `passenger` both installed and working fine. However, when I change the `nginx` config file at `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` as follows

```
....
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1;
....
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;                                                                                                                                                                                    

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;                                                                                                                                                            

    location / {
        root   /home/path_to_my_app/public;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

it doesn't work. I'm not able to call my rails code. It keeps saying *404* error.

I restarted the `nginx` using `service nginx restart` which returned `OK`, but still no luck.

Can anyone tell how to debug this. Where should I check what all applications my passenger is running? What is the part I'm missing?

**EDIT**: I'm following this [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app) very closely

Comment: Sometimes when you restart `nginx` all seems to be OK when it really isn't. Try finding the error log (sometimes at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`) and see if any errors are printed out when you restart.

Comment: @MartinKonecny: The error doesn't show any error. It just says PassengerAgent online. There are no errors in that log. Is there any other place where I should check??

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can tell me whats going on??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no `/home/path_to_my_app/public` directory.

In Passenger version 5.0.7 directory access has been changed. Now if root directory doesn't exist it falls back to nginx to search index.html and gives 404 error if there is now such file.

> [Nginx] The Nginx module now looks for index.html if the path ends in
>   / so that it works intuitively, without needing to use try_files.

https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/04/29/passenger-5-0-7/

Answer (score 0):

"location /" means all the HTTP request will be handled by this location's handler but there isn't one so you will get "404 not found". I guess you mean that your home page is index.html so change "location /" to "location =/" will fixed your problem.

---

update

`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /path/to/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }`

There is no need add location for simple app.

Comment: That did not fix the problem. It still says 404 error. How do I check whether my rails app is running??

Comment: passenger will handle all the request for you, so just set root path of public.

Answer (score 0):

If your server log says that passenger agents are online and if you run `sudo passenger-status` and see your application listed, then it would appear the agent is setup correctly.

Are you trying to access the site using localhost? If you're trying to access it from outside the server, you'll need to set `server_name` to either your domain or an IP address (and restart nginx after any changes). If you run `curl http://localhost` on the server, do you see the html from your site, or just another 404?